# Can you make a Microsoft Biometrics program that doesn't require admin?

Tags: c#, admin, biometrics

I'm trying to make a program that utilizes the Microsoft Biometrics API with a fingerprint reader. So far I've gotten to the point where I can scan the finger and get data from that.

But the only problem is that I can't run the program and make the scanner work without Administrator Rights. This is a problem for the application I'm making as the tablet it's supposed to run on is not supposed to run as Admin while this happens.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the answer to this is No. It's impossible.